# Can I cache an include for use elsewhere in a template?

Tags: templating, database, performance

I have an include that is doing a DB query (it generates a menu of entries) and that's used more than once on a template.

Is there a way I can cache the first parse for later use to cut down on DB hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would wrap the code in your include in `cache` tags and use the keyword [`globally`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache#globally) with it.

```
{% cache globally for 3 years %}
```